# VB5 Project on Jenkins Slave: Build errors

Tags: jenkins, vb6, master-slave

I am attempting to build a VB5 (legacy...I know) project using Jenkins and a Master/Slave configuration.

The master checks out the project on the slave then runs a batch file which looks like the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\devstudio\vb\vb5" /make project.vbp
```

The project contains a custom DLL which is registered on the slave via regsvr32. This dll supplies a control which is used in the project.

During the **make** command above, the following errors are received on the slave:

> Error during load. Refer to [path to .log file] for details

The log file contains the following error:

> Line 63: Cannot load control [control name]

If I run the **make** command directly on the command line of the slave it works perfectly.

Here are some configuration details:

Master:
Windows 7 32bit running latest version of Jenkins.

Slave:
Windows XP connecting to Master via command line and slave.jar
Logged in account has admin access

Comment: The account the slave is running under has the control registered as well?

Comment: Hi Rene. Yes the account where the DLL is registered is the same as the account that is logged on when the Master Jenkins instance requests a job to run on the Slave

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. You could try to run [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to see if it fails to find registry entries or can't find files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was an error on my part. I was reading the contents of the .VBP project file and replacing the version number using a java program. I was using the wrong line endings when I wrote the content back to the project file and this was causing errors on the *make* command